# Postgis 2.1: ERROR: Shell is not a line - SQL state: XX000

Tags: postgis, contour

My current setup is PostgreSQL 9.3.6 & PostGIS 2.1.5

I have a table with contour lines (multilinestrings) that I wish to group by the attribute 'elevation', and make polygons out of them. The lines, hovewer, were derived from different sheets, so it might be that one of these lines suddently ends exactly where another (with the same elevation) begins. This is an example by selecting one of those lines in QGIS: [image: contour lines]

I get a strange error message:
`ERROR: Shell is not a line - SQL state: XX000`
when I try to run this query:

```
select st_multi(st_makepolygon(st_union(the_geom)))
from import.contour
group by elevation
```

however if I run

```
select distinct geometrytype(the_geom), st_isvalid(the_geom)
from import.contour;
```

I get as result:

```
|  geometrytype  | st_isvalid |  
|----------------|------------|  
| MULTILINESTRING|     t      |
```

So it seems to be everything ok for me,...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I would use ST_BuildArea instead.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the way ST_MakePolygon expects the input geometries.

ST_Union is giving you MULITLINESTRINGs, but does not actually combine them.  ST_MakePolygon is expecting a complete ring from what I can tell.

Use [ST_Polygonize](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html) instead.  This should give you the result you want.

```sql
WITH contour AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 10 0, 10 10)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (10 10, 0 10, 0 0)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (20 0, 30 0, 30 10)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (30 10, 20 10, 20 0)'))
        ) c(elevation, the_geom)
    )
select st_astext(st_polygonize(the_geom))
from contour
group by elevation

-- "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((10 10,10 0,0 0,0 10,10 10)),POLYGON((30 10,30 0,20 0,20 10,30 10)))"

WITH contour AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 10 0, 10 10)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (10 10, 0 10, 0 0)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (20 0, 30 0, 30 10)')),
        (10,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (30 10, 20 10, 20 0)'))
        ) c(elevation, the_geom)
    )
select st_multi(st_makepolygon(st_union(the_geom)))
from contour
group by elevation

-- ERROR:  Shell is not a line
```